# Change the email appearing as contact detail when there is a 403 access denied error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-403, google-cloud-iam

I am facing a strange issue in GCP portal. Any help would be appreciated.I want to change the email address which appears as a contact detail whenever you get a 403 Access denied error while accessing a site hosted in GCP. I tried everything but no success any help would be appreciated.

Currently the error message says this

"If you should have access please contact abc.gmail.com"

and I want to change it to

"If you should have access please contact xyz.gmail.com"

Comment: Is the email the same as the `Project Owner` or is this the email address from the `OAuth consent screen`?

Comment: Hi John, you were right to point me in the direction of OAuth Consent screen, Please submit that as an answer, I will validate that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As John mentioned in the comments, the problem was in OAuth Consent Screen. Make sure your re an project owner to have your email appear in OAuth Consent Screen.